# Python can't get polyfit function to work

Tags: python

I have an array "uniqueMonths" with 12 elements (1 to 12) and one array of 8991 values. I want to use polyfit function to these values, but I don't get any output on aa variable and no error code either. Maybe you could help me what is wrong? Code:

```
aa = np.polyfit(uniqueMonth,values, 1)
```

Comment: Please [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Currently, your question is too vague. A starting point anyway: [`np.polyfit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html#numpy.polyfit) takes as input two arrays of equal length.

Comment: The size of `values` should either be equal to size of `uniqueMonth`(when both are one dimensional) or the size of `values` needs to be k times the size of 1d `uniqueMonth`, with each column representating a set dataset

Comment: Refer to these docs: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html